# Global clustering coefficient for directed network

Tags: networkx, social-networking, network-analysis

Global clustering coefficient gives an outline of the clustering in the entire network. From theory, this measure can be applied to both undirected and directed networks.
Networx library provides a function `average_clustering(g)` that calculates global clustering for undirected networks but not for directed ones. Is there a way to implement the global clustering coefficient for directed networks in Python or are there other libraries that do this?

Thanks

I searched for information to no avail, on stack overflow there is another very similar question but got no answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please be clear as to what metric you want to consider: global clustering coefficient or the average clustering coefficient? Remember, the two are not the same.

The networkx function `average_clustering(g)` you point to simply finds the average of the local clustering coefficients of all the nodes NOT the global clustering coefficient. The local clustering coefficient for a node is the ratio of the number of triangles formed by it with its neighbors and the total possible of number of triangles it could have formed. On the other hand, GCC is defined as the ratio of the number of closed triplets and the number of total (open and closed) triplets for the entire graph.

I don't know about GCC as I haven't come to need it thus far. But average clustering coefficient for directed graph can be found by implementing the logic laid out in this paper: [Clustering in Complex Directed Networks](https://journals.aps.org/pre/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevE.76.026107). It's doable using python. You'd have to find the cube of the sum of the adjacency matrix and the transpose of the adj mat. Then for each node, *i* you'd have to find the *iith* element in this cubed matrix which shall give you the number of triangles formed by that node. Then all you need is the number of total possible triangles which can be found-as given in the paper-by [this formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6taeV.png).

After you can store the LCC of each node in a dictionary and then take the average of the values to find the average_clustering_coefficient.